# How do you prevent VS Code from reopening file at previous scroll position

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VS Code I'm experiencing unexpected behaviour. When I re-open a file, the editor opens at the previous scroll position.

**Example:**

- I open a long file, scroll half way down make some edits, save and close the file
- I reopen the same file again. It will open at the same scroll position where I made the edits half way down the file.

[image: screencast]

I expected that the editor would reopen the file back at the top of the file like in other text editors.

I haven't been able to find any settings that would explain this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unexpected behaviour

It is actually very much the expected behavior: restore the workbench in its exact state.

This is confirmed by [issue 24394](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24394), which is asking (indirectly) what you want.

> This behavior should be opt-in and disabled by default.
> I often open a file, scroll to the bottom looking for something and close it then.

> Now nearly every file I open starts at the bottom instead of the top and in 90% of the times the first thing I do is scroll to the top.

[Commit 27cb886](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/27cb8862c95fa81688b65ab51b19998adbdca08c) from Sept. 2018, VSCode 1.28, introduces the setting

```
'workbench.editor.restoreViewState': {
        'type': 'boolean',
        'description': nls.localize('restoreViewState', 
         "Restores the last view state (e.g. scroll position) when re-opening files 
          after they have been closed."),
        'default': true,
},
```

That fixes the issue.

---

Update [August 2020, VSCode 1.49](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101110)

> ### Allow to configure workbench.editor.restoreViewState per language

> When we close a file and then re-open it, VS Code will restore the cursor position.

> In many cases this is desired.
> However, in some cases it is not, therefore it would be useful to provide a setting for this and allow it to be configured differently depending on the language being used.
>
> For example: when I run `git commit` in terminal, the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file will open in VS Code.
> Ideally my cursor would be positioned at the top so I can start writing my commit message right away. However, many times my cursor is positioned elsewhere, presumably because VS Code is trying to restore it to the position when I closed this file the last time I wrote a commit message.
>
> This also happens when I run git rebase --interactive and the rebase todo list is opened in VS Code.

This is now fixed:

> - configure `workbench.editor.restoreViewState` for a language, e.g. `markdown`
> - open a couple of files including markdown and scroll + set a selection you can memorize
> - switch between tabs and verify view state is restored
> - reload window and do the same and verify view state is restored
> - close a non-markdown file and open it again and verify view state is restored
> - close the markdown file and open it again and verify view state is NOT restored

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that issue. I'll follow up there.

I assumed it was an intentional "feature" however it was unexpected behaviour for me that felt like a bug. It's the one thing about VS Code the annoys me enough to make me want to switch back to my former editor.

Comment: It's not the expected behavior to someone who doesn't expect it. E.g. a Visual Studio user.

Comment: @xr280xr Indeed. I don't know Visual Studio itself well enough, but I can see why this would be unsettling.

Answer (score 4):

just add the following line in the settings.json:

```
"workbench.editor.restoreViewState": false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the filename when you run VScode. the file is shown at the beginning. For example, I have a file named 2gaussians.py. When I first started on this file I entered `code` at the command prompt on the command line. I opened my file from within VScode. I worked on my file and I quit with my cursor at the bottom of the file. When I ran VScode the next time I typed `code 2gaussians.py` on the command line.  VScode opened and my file, 2gaussians.py, was displayed in the editor from line 1.

Comment: I think this happening because you are working with a single file, and quitting the editor before opening the file again.

My problem is when I'm working in a project/directory with multiple files and switching between files without closing the application.

Thanks for the feedback though.